# Rename files in a tree that have extension included in base name

Tags: regex, linux, centos, find, rename

I have a bunch of files in a directory (and lots of child directories) on a CentOS server that have the extension accidentally stuck to the base name, like this.

```
12345jpg
```

I want to rename them all to

```
12345.jpg
```

I'm close with this command but can't quite get the rename regex to work.

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.*" -exec rename 's/([0-9]{5})(.*)/$1.$2/'
```

Update: Would it be better to use sed instead of rename?  Like this? (which also isn't working at the moment)

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.*" -exec sed -i '' s/([0-9]{5})(.*)/1.2/g {} ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `rename` utility can handle backreferences.

Here's a portable posix-only solution:

```
find . -type f -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?*' \
       -not -name '*.*' |while IFS= read file; do
  dir="${file%/*}"
  file="${file#$dir/}"
  B="${file#?????}"
  A="${file%$B}"
  mv -i "$dir/$file" "$dir/$A.$B"
done
```

This uses shell globbing (which lacks quantifiers, thus the redundancy) to ensure we're only renaming files that have the expected five leading digits and then at least one more character while excluding files with a dot in their names.

It then loops through line by line (yes, this will break if you have a line break in your file names—don't do that!). I'm explicitly clearing `$IFS` so spaces aren't interpreted as field separators.

Within the while loop, I massage the file name. First, I extract the directory name (which is `./` if there isn't one; be careful if you deviate from `find . …`) and then alter the `$file` variable to store only the file name. I then assign `$B` to the file name missing the first five characters (which `find` has already required to be digits) and `$A` to be those first five characters. Now we can do the rename with the extra dot.

I used `mv -i` as a safety. This will interactively ask about anything you'd overwrite before doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly escape your regex and use `\1.\2` in replacements

```
s/\([0-9]\{5\}\)\(.*\)/\1.\2/
```

For instance:

```
$ echo '12345jpg' | sed 's/\([0-9]\{5\}\)\(.*\)/\1.\2/'
12345.jpg
```